# Adding attributes to the xml elements made from the <list>

Tags: c#, xml, list, serialization

Here is my class  code:

```
//class CenyKategorie

public class CenyKategorie
{
    string nazwa { get; set; }
    double cena { get; set; }

    public CenyKategorie()
    {

    }

public CenyKategorie(string Nazwa, double Cena)
    {
        nazwa = Nazwa;
        cena = Cena;
    }
}
```

And here is code of the method:

```
private void SomeMethod()
{
List<CenyKategorie> cenykat = new List<CenyKategorie>
                {
                    new CenyKategorie("Kat A", 12),
                    new CenyKategorie("Kat B", 15)
                    };                
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Program Files\file.xml", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
                {
                    XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<CenyKategorie>));
                    xs.Serialize(fs, cenykat);          
                }     
}
```

The .xml output is following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfCenyKategorie xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <CenyKategorie>
    <nazwa>Kat A</nazwa>
    <cena>12</cena>
  </CenyKategorie>
  <CenyKategorie>
    <nazwa>Kat B</nazwa>
    <cena>15</cena>
  </CenyKategorie>
</ArrayOfCenyKategorie>
```

Now I want to add an attribute to the  element to make it look like this:

```
<nazwa="example1">Kat A</nazwa>
```

But I don't know how to do it via list, can I count on your help?